# Linux firewall, ADSL bonding, two default routes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, routing, nat

I am trying to set up a Linux firewall (ubuntu 14.04) to use two bonded ADSL lines for load balancing purposes.  I found by searching the forum link to this: http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html but it does not work in my case, as I do not have two physical interfaces to separate the ADSL connections.
My setup is now

```
WAN1 - ADSLrouter1 (192.168.1.1) \
                                  - 192.168.1.3 Firewall - private IP LAN 
WAN2 - ADSLrouter2 (192.168.1.2) /
```

I have added two default routes with weight 1 for load balancing.  Everything works fine from the firewall to the internet.  However, the FW needs to do masquerading as well. From hosts in internal LANs, ping to outside world works fine. I have just added

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

where eth0 has ip addr 192.168.1.3. TCP connections do not work too well; I just get connection reset by peer messages. I know the problem is in the two routes as if I remove one, everything works smoothly.

I assume the problem is in masquerading and things go wrong when tcp streams get routed different routes. Can I fix this somehow or do I need another NIC to follow the instructions I found?

Hannu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. You need two NICs, mainly because your Linux firewall is sending outbound packets in a round-robin fashion when it comes to select a route as they both have the same metric.

Having two NICs will just do round-robin per NIC and not per route, keeping each TCP connection on the same NIC.

Keep in mind this could still cause you trouble with some applications, e.g. online banking. 
Most of the web applications out there will keep a valid session as long as you've got a valid cookie, however banking usually ties that also to the source IP and, you probably know this already, HTTP uses several TCP connections in order to fetch all the resources on a website. As soon as one of those TCP connections is sent from a different NIC (i.e. different ADSL provider hence different source IP) your cookie will be rendered invalid and the banking session finished.

If you could somehow implement some affinity (user UA going to site SA use link LA) you won't have this issue and as long as you expire this entries in a reasonable time you wouldn't have RAM issues on your Linux firewall neither.

Maybe you'd just prefer to profile your network usage based on source and add some policy based routing (aka source routing) to statically balance service among your available links.

Comment: Thanks. can I do load balancing in this setup without the second nic? I am just now trying mangling and firewall marks and probabilities, just in case this would do the trick. No luck this far, though.

Comment: You could do policy based routing without the second NIC. The previous section on the same guide you linked shows [how to](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.html#LARTC.RPDB.SIMPLE). In this case, the load balancing decisions will be taken by you, e.g.: HR department's subnet will use the slow link, IT guys will get the beefier one, $BOSS will use the same as the IT guys, etc

Comment: Thanks. This I cannot do for certain reasons how these connections are used.  I asked for a second NIC to be installed there. I managed to get something working, but now every second incoming packet of NATted traffic is dropped despite the stream coming through the same interface.  

ANyway, thanks for your help.